# Web Api 2 - Check if User Is Logged In

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am still finding my way around in ASP.NET.

I am experimenting with getting Angular code talking to a Web API 2 end point, which will only be accessed from  within the solution itself.

One thing I want to be able to do is to show or hide edit buttons based on whether the current user is logged in or browsing anonymously.

I could do this in an MVC view by checking `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` but I'm curious how I could do it with a pure Angular page, with no .NET coded in it.

I thought I could just do something like this

```
public class AuthorizationController : ApiController
{
     public HttpResponseMessage Get()
     {
          if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          {
               return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Ok");
          }
          else
          {
               return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "You are not authorized");
          }
     };
}
```

And then call it like this

```
$http.get("../api/authorization")
     .then(function (response) 
           {
                if(response.status=="200") 
                {
                     // logged in
                }
                else
                {
                    // not logged in
                }
           });
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't do what I was hoping. If the user is not logged in, the API code hits the line creating an error response, but what it actually returns to the Angular callback is

```
{"data":"<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\r\n <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\r\n <title>Log in - My ASP.NET Application</title>\r\n <link href=\"/Content/bootstrap.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>\r\n<link href=\"/Content/site.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/>\r\n\r\n <script src=\"/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js\"></script>\r\n\r\n\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n <div class=\"navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top\">\r\n <div class=\"container\">\r\n <div class=\"navbar-header\">\r\n <button type=\"button\" class=\"navbar-toggle\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-target=\".navbar-collapse\">\r\n <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>\r\n <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>\r\n <span class=\"icon-bar\"></span>\r\n </button>\r\n <a class=\"navbar-brand\" href=\"/\">Application name</a>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"navbar-collapse collapse\">\r\n <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav\">\r\n <li><a href=\"/\">Home</a></li>\r\n <li><a href=\"/Home/About\">About</a></li>\r\n <li><a href=\"/Home/Contact\">Contact</a></li>\r\n </ul>\r\n <ul class=\"nav navbar-nav navbar-right\">\r\n <li><a href=\"/Account/Register\" id=\"registerLink\">Register</a></li>\r\n <li><a href=\"/Account/Login\" id=\"loginLink\">Log in</a></li>\r\n </ul>\r\n\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"container body-content\">\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n<h2>Log in.</h2>\r\n<div class=\"row\">\r\n <div class=\"col-md-8\">\r\n <section id=\"loginForm\">\r\n<form action=\"/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fauthorization\" class=\"form-horizontal\" method=\"post\" role=\"form\"><input name=\"__RequestVerificationToken\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"5h-wFJ5pn4Vq8uI15BbzTvAwAFuudI1jaF_YsHfpAp9YFaeArEkO4P6i5bFMYgSs6OY6BXDEHzNLFpxYA-IvQJlr7zYY8Bgj9mErF1dgMQQ1\" /> <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>\r\n <hr />\r\n <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n <label class=\"col-md-2 control-label\" for=\"Email\">Email</label>\r\n <div class=\"col-md-10\">\r\n <input class=\"form-control\" data-val=\"true\" data-val-email=\"The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.\" data-val-required=\"The Email field is required.\" id=\"Email\" name=\"Email\" type=\"text\" value=\"\" />\r\n <span class=\"field-validation-valid text-danger\" data-valmsg-for=\"Email\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"></span>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n <label class=\"col-md-2 control-label\" for=\"Password\">Password</label>\r\n <div class=\"col-md-10\">\r\n <input class=\"form-control\" data-val=\"true\" data-val-required=\"The Password field is required.\" id=\"Password\" name=\"Password\" type=\"password\" />\r\n <span class=\"field-validation-valid text-danger\" data-valmsg-for=\"Password\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"></span>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n <div class=\"col-md-offset-2 col-md-10\">\r\n <div class=\"checkbox\">\r\n <input data-val=\"true\" data-val-required=\"The Remember me? field is required.\" id=\"RememberMe\" name=\"RememberMe\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"true\" /><input name=\"RememberMe\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"false\" />\r\n <label for=\"RememberMe\">Remember me?</label>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n <div class=\"col-md-offset-2 col-md-10\">\r\n <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Log in\" class=\"btn btn-default\" />\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n <p>\r\n <a href=\"/Account/Register\">Register as a new user</a>\r\n </p>\r\n</form> </section>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class=\"col-md-4\">\r\n <section id=\"socialLoginForm\">\r\n \r\n<h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>\r\n<hr />\r\n <div>\r\n <p>\r\n There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href=\"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=403804\">this article</a>\r\n for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.\r\n </p>\r\n </div>\r\n\r\n\r\n </section>\r\n </div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n <hr />\r\n <footer>\r\n <p>&copy; 2016 - My ASP.NET Application</p>\r\n </footer>\r\n </div>\r\n\r\n <script src=\"/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js\"></script>\r\n\r\n <script src=\"/Scripts/bootstrap.js\"></script>\r\n<script src=\"/Scripts/respond.js\"></script>\r\n\r\n \r\n <script src=\"/Scripts/jquery.validate.js\"></script>\r\n<script src=\"/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js\"></script>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->\r\n<script type=\"application/json\" id=\"__browserLink_initializationData\">\r\n {\"appName\":\"Firefox\",\"requestId\":\"69b5785bb7f0400088c465aa19c19c8a\"}\r\n</script>\r\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://localhost:55784/9f4b9571f5a149d8a3ad956c641aff65/browserLink\" async=\"async\"></script>\r\n<!-- End Browser Link -->\r\n\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n","status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"../api/authorization","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

So it seems to be returning a log in page. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or am I just completely barking up the wrong tree with this approach?

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem. Basically, if I return Unauthorized() from my API  controller, it seems to be converted into a respose with status 200, and data representing a log in page. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and actually force the controller to return the 401?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you're using forms authentication. By default, forms authentication will detect an unauthenticated event in the pipeline (401) and convert it to a redirect (302) to the login page. If your client is automatically following that redirect (most do), then you'll ultimately get the content of the login page with HTTP success status code (200).

There are two reasonably straight-forward solutions to this:

1. Don't use forms authentication (OK, not entirely straight-forward if you don't have an alternative authentication middleware to hand).
2. Set the [`HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect.aspx) property to true.

Per documentation for `HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`:

> By default, forms authentication converts HTTP 401 status codes to 302
>   in order to redirect to the login page. This isn't appropriate for
>   certain classes of errors, such as when authentication succeeds but
>   authorization fails, or when the current request is an AJAX or web
>   service request. This property provides a way to suppress the redirect
>   behavior and send the original status code to the client.

And regarding the value of the property:

> **true** if forms authentication redirection should be suppressed;
>   otherwise, **false**.

For further reading, and full credit to Phil Haack as my first source of easy information on the topic, check out his [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is regarding the server side web api.
 but If someone want to examine another approach,
 and it is possible to do it on the client side using javascript/typescript
 maybe this approach can help future readers:
I prefer to do it locally, using [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) and save unnecessary calls to the server.
`this.serverResponse.expires_in`is the expiration time in seconds.

extract the expiration date from the web api server:

```
var tokenexpiration: Date = new Date();
tokenexpiration.setSeconds(new Date().getSeconds() + parseInt(this.serverResponse.expires_in))
console.log(tokenexpiration);
```

than you can save it to localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('expirationdate',tokenexpiration)
```

and with simple condition you can check whenever you need if the token was expired.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). You can decorate your controllers with it or some of its methods and then handle the `UnAuthorized` exception in AngularJS (status 401 I think).

.Net will decide if a request is authorized or not based on cookies most of the times, but this really depends on the authentication scheme you're using.

Comment: this was my first approach. I used the Authorize attribute. But it also returns the HTML for a log in page, rather than a 401. I think there must be some setting in my request, or response, that I need to set to tell the API not to try and redirect to the Log In page, but just to return a 401